# Getting text in a specific order in text view by random generator

Tags: android, eclipse

I want some text to appear in the text view in a specific sequence `info 1, info 2, info 3, info 4, info 5` when the button is pressed.

However it presently appears randomly: `info 4, info 1, info 3, info 4`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String[] answers = {

                "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5"

                };

                String answer = "";

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(answers.length);
                answer = Integer.toString(randomNumber);

                answer = answers[randomNumber];
                answerLabel.setText(answer);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Use Collection.shuffle() and iterate from 0 to n

Comment: You are making it random by using your `randomGenerator`. Why are you doing that if you don't want it to be random?

Comment: bro could you please elaborate?

Comment: This code does things, then undos the things it does, then doesother things, and you want it to do something completely different. Gotta love stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you please refer me to some tutorial you know of so that i would be able to achieve what i am trying.

Comment: I moved what you want to the very top of the question for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following should work:

```
private String[] _answers = { "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5" };
private int _position = _answers.length - 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            answerLabel.setText(_answers[_position]);
            if (_position != 0) {
                _position--;
            }
            else {
                _position = _answers.length - 1;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Working great, but how can i reverse this order, i.e i am at info 5 and i want to go back to info 4, than info 3 and so on by pressing another button.

Comment: An easy way to is just reverse your string array so it was "info 5", "info4", "info3". But if you don't want to do that let me know and I'll edit my answer to swap it round

Comment: Dreagen, i want that the xml has 2 buttons, one which carries the information like info1 info2 info3 etc, and the other button when pressed at any instance like while it is pressed when info4 is showing, after pressing that it goes to ino2 info 2 and info1. And bro thanks for your great intrest

Comment: I have edited my answer, if I understand what you're after that should hopefully do it

Comment: its not what i am intending to do :(

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. I'm struggling to understand what it is you're trying to do. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
private final int answerNumber = 0;
private final String[] answers = {"info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answerLabel.setText(answers[answerNumber]);
            answerNumber = answerNumber == answers.size() - 1? 0: answerNumber + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Working great, but how can i reverse this order, i.e i am at info 5 and i want to go back to info 4, than info 3 and so on by pressing another button.